# Handle response.body == null in RX

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, rx-java, rx-android

i use `Rx` in android below

```
        repository.getUserList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ response ->

                val userList = response.body()!!
                view.showUser(userList)
                
            }, { throwable ->
                handlerException(view, throwable)
            }).addToDisposable()
```

It works.

But sometimes `response.body()` is null, maybe network error or server not response,
then app will crash.

so i have to add `try catch` like this

```
        repository.getUserList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ response ->

                try {
                    val userList = response.body()!!
                    view.showUser(userList)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    handleException(view, e)
                }
            }, { throwable ->
                handleException(view, throwable)
            }).addToDisposable()
```

But I think there should be a better way to handler error in rx.
can anyone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter operator

```
.filter { it != null }
```

this was RX way but you can use kotlin null safety like this:

```
.subscribe({ response ->

            response.body()?.let{
            view.showUser(userList)
              }
        }
```

hope it helped

Comment: Thanks. But i think it the same way like `try catch`.